# call fileUpload control using asp button

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an application that will show an image when I click a button and browse on the dialog.

this is my sample layout and code:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|          CLICK HERE TO INSERT IMAGE               |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" cssClass="containment-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="display:none;"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="MainImage" runat="server" CssClass="mainImage" ImageUrl="~/Image/ClickHere.png" OnClick="MainImage_Click"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

and my .CS file

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + FileUpload1.ClientID + "').click();");

    }
   protected void MainImage_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I can click the "CLICK HERE TO INSERT IMAGE" and shows the file dialog, but my problem is how to get the selected image and show it on the buttonImage.

Comment: Do you mean - show the selected image on the ImageButton *before* it's uploaded to the server ?

Comment: Not really. Just after I click the "CLICK HERE TO INSERT IMAGE" browse the image, and show it on the ImageButton.

Answer (score 1):

Then You need to use the FileUpload's `PostedFile.SaveAs` function to upload the image to a named folder of your website, and set the ImageURL property of the ImageButton as appropriate: -

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/image.jpg"));
```

Make sure the user your app pool is running under has write permissions to this folder (upload in the example above)

Edit: -

If you don't want to save the image, your task is harder but could be solved by: -

1. Storing the PostedFile's InputStream to a Session variable
2. Create an HttpHandler that returns this stream
3. Point your ImageButton's ImageURL at the HttpHandler instead of an image URL

Comment: What if I don't want to save on my folder just for preview purposes?